# Why do Afro-Caribbeans have English names whereas Indo-Caribbeans still have Indian(ish) names?

Tags: slavery, colonization, imperialism, atlantic-slave-trade, caribbean

Why don't Afro-Caribbeans have African names or Indo-Caribbeans have English names? Did colonizers find it difficult to pronounce African names but not Indian names?

Further to this question, if this was due to Africans being slaves and Indians being contract workers, why were only Africans used as slaves in the Caribbean and not Indians?

Comment: Afro Carribeans are descendants of slaves, Indo-Caribbean are  descendant of 'free'  workers. A master of a slave may define the name of a slave, but an employer  normally don't define the name of the employee.

Comment: I agree with the @knut explanation, but let me add that "Indo Carribeans" are not  descendants of the indigenous population (Caribs). They came from other parts of America.

Comment: @Alex Before I wrote I checked for [Indo-Caribbean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Caribbean) and found a wikipedia article: They are descendent from India. There is no american origin.

Comment: @knut: wherever they come from, they are not descendants of slaves, so your answer is correct.

Comment: Knut, please expand your comment a bit and put it in as an answer. :)

Comment: @knut - With a bit of digging, I could find you a Public Enemy song that helps explains this. :-)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this assertion is true?

Answer (score 14):

[Afro Carribeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afro-Caribbean):

> Afro-Caribbeans are Caribbean people who trace their heritage to Sub-Saharan Africa [...] Between the 16th and 19th centuries, European-led triangular trade brought African people to work as slaves in the Caribbean on various plantations.

These Afro Carribeans are descendants of slaves. The slaves had no rights and a master of a slave may define the name of a slave. Especially if the master doesn't want to learn 'strange' names.

[Indo-Caribbean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Caribbean):

> Indo-Caribbeans are Caribbean people with roots in India. They are mostly descendants of the original indentured workers brought by the British, the Dutch and the French during colonial times.

The Indo-Caribbeans arrived after the end of slavery at the [West Indies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_indenture_system#Indian_labour_transportation_to_West_Indies). They were 'free' workers and an employer normally doesn't change the name of the employee.